# Format dates according to the format of users' computer

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, reporting

I am formatting the dates in my SSRS report. I've noticed that, on two different computers where the default date formats are different, my report shows dates in the same format. How can my SSRS report format dates according to the date formats of the users' computers?

Comment: @pedram Which format? I don't know. I only know that I want the date format of the report to follow that of the user's computer. I have tried nothing because I don't think that a single format string will represent more than one format. Different users will call the report from different computers at different times. The actual format cannot be determined until the users call the report.

Comment: @pedram But I have tried to call the report from different computers, and to change the date formats of the computer. (A user can personalize the date format of Windows.) Unfortunately, the format of the dates in the report does not follow to change.

Comment: how about using =Globals!ExecutionTime add this as an expression and check.